# window.history.back() sometimes refreshes and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, html

I am finding that when I use the back button on the browser or window.history.back(); the page being loaded sometimes refreshes and sometimes doesn't. I have not been able to reproduce this reliably but it is causing a problem in that I do not want the page being gone back to refresh is it displays different information every time it is refreshed.

I either need to ensure the back button and window.history.back(); do not cause a refresh, or I need to be able to detect on the page that it is being redisplayed as the result of a back button so I can somehow stop it being refreshed.

Is anyone able to explain why it sometimes refreshes and sometimes doesn't and what if anything I can do about it?

Comment: Guess that's because of the cache settings for each page, if it has no cache or it expired, my guess is that it would refresh

Answer (score 0):

check out the html5 history api

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

I never implemented it by myself, because angular is managing the history by itself, but I think it should solve your problem

Comment: That is an interesting document but can't see how it solves my problem.